# Java Check If Two JTextField Has The Same Content

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext

I have two JTextFields txf1 and txf2.

In both of them I input the same content (for example: "test").

I made and If statement:

```
if (txf1.getText() == txf2.getText()) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Why it prints out the error message? I even made a `System.out.println(txf1.getText())` and `System.out.println(txf2.getText())` and the same looks equal, but prints out the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparison in Java is done using `String#equals`, using `==` means you are comparing the memory reference of the objects, which won't always return `true` when you think it should.

Try something more like....

```
if (txf1.getText().equals(txf2.getText())) {
```

...instead

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this good practice which makes your text box entries efficient.

```
if (txf1.getText().trim().equals(txf2.getText().trim())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method to compare Strings. `==` only compares the object reference. `equals` compares the actual content of the Strings.

Your code should be something like this:

```
if (txf1.getText().equals(txf2.getText())) {
  System.out.println("Equal");
} else {
  System.out.println("Error");
}
```